# elasticsearch upgrade from 1.7.x to 5.2.x

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the right way to upgrade elasticsearch from 1.7 to 5.2?

I've tried to upgrade it to 2.4 version first and done reindex procedure and then I installed elasticsearch v.5.2. When v.5.2 was started in logs saw this messages:

> 3) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalStateException: The
>   index [[logstash-2017.01.15/tk1-FBLGTQGl0vVW1xxPpg]] was created with
>   version [1.7.3] but the minimum compatible version is [2.0.0-beta1].
>   It should be re-indexed in Elasticsearch 2.x before upgrading to
>   5.2.2.

Comment: How do you do the reindex?

Comment: I use two queries: `curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_reindex` to reindex like in this article [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) and then I delete old index.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reindex-upgrade.html), if you are running an Elasticsearch 1.x cluster, you have two options:

- First upgrade to Elasticsearch 2.4.x, reindex the old indices, then upgrade to 5.x.
- Create a new 5.x cluster and use reindex-from-remote to import indices directly from the 1.x cluster.

[Reindex in place](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reindex-upgrade.html#reindex-upgrade-inplace)

> The easiest way to reindex old (1.x) indices in place is to use the Elasticsearch Migration Plugin. You will need to upgrade to Elasticsearch 2.3.x or 2.4.x first.
>
> The reindex utility provided in the migration plugin does the following:
>
> - Creates a new index with the Elasticsearch version appended to the old index name (e.g. my_index-2.4.1), copying the mappings and settings from the old index. Refresh is disabled on the new index and the number of replicas is set to 0 for efficient reindexing.
> - Sets the old index to read only to ensure that no data is written to the old index.
> - Reindexes all documents from the old index to the new index.
> - Resets the refresh_interval and number_of_replicas to the values used in the old index, and waits for the index to become green.
> - Adds any aliases that existed on the old index to the new index.
> - Deletes the old index.
> - Adds an alias to the new index with the old index name, e.g. alias my_index points to index my_index-2.4.1.
>
> At the end of this process, you will have a new 2.x index which can be used by an Elasticsearch 5.x cluster.

[Upgrading with reindex-from-remote](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reindex-upgrade.html#reindex-upgrade-remote)

> If you are running a 1.x cluster and would like to migrate directly to 5.x without first migrating to 2.x, you can do so using reindex-from-remote.
>
> You will need to set up a 5.x cluster alongside your existing 1.x cluster. The 5.x cluster needs to have access to the REST API of the 1.x cluster.
>
> For each 1.x index that you want to transfer to the 5.x cluster, you
>   will need to:
>
> - Create a new index in 5.x with the appropriate mappings and settings.
> - Set the refresh_interval to -1 and set number_of_replicas to 0 for faster reindexing.
> - Use reindex-from-remote to pull documents from the 1.x index into the new 5.x index. If you run the reindex job in the background (with wait_for_completion set to false), the reindex request will return a task_id which can be used to monitor progress of the reindex job in the task API: GET _tasks/TASK_ID.
> - Once reindex has completed, set the refresh_interval and number_of_replicas to the desired values (the defaults are 30s and 1 respectively).
> - Once the new index has finished replication, you can delete the old index.